# Do the sum of some function belong to specific spaces

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Consider the following function $f(x)$ on $[a,c]$ for $a,c \in \mathbb{R}$

\begin{cases} 
      h (x) &a< x<b \\
      g(x) & b\leq  x<c 
   \end{cases}
Assume h and g are $C^1$ on their intervals.

I wonder which condition need to be satisfied such that $f$ is in $H^1([a,c])$.

Actually there should be no problems since the functions are $C^1$ so the weak derivative coincides with the classical one.  Is there a issue with my argumentation here?

Comment: When you say $h$ is $C^1$ on its interval, I'm assuming you mean on the closed interval $[a,b]$ (unclear from your question). If not, then take $h(x)= \frac 1 {b-x}$ and the derivative is not square integrable because of the singularity at the left of $b$, and $f$ is not in $H^1$. This problem goes away if you assume that both $h$ and $g$ are $C^1$ on the closed intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your remark.  I think f has to be continuous in $b$. Are there further conditions?

Comment: Sorry my example above was really for the derivative of $h$, not $h$ itself. Here's a better example. Take $a=-c=-1$ and $b=0$. Consider $h(x)= \sqrt{|x|}$ and $g(x)=0$. Then $f$ is continuous at $b=0$ but $h^\prime$ is not square integrable because of the singularity.

Comment: I see, but h would not be $C^1$ in this case

Comment: It would be $C^1$... on the open interval $(a,b)$. You never specified if $C^1$ was on the closed interval $[a,b]$ or open $(a,b)$. That was exactly the question I was asking you at the beginning of this thread.